# NodeJS Module Exports with Additional Required Files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to break my `nodejs` code up into as small of files as possible to keep things modular. I have an `app.js` that is needing to use another method that I have moved to `utils.js`. The utils file however has a method that has a requirement for another library.

Should my `utils.js` file be "requiring" dependencies or should all those go in my `app.js`?

```
// app.js
var utilities = require('./utilities');
..
return utilities.anotherMethod();



// utils.js
module.exports = {
    producer: function () {
        // Handle mapping of fields depending on the source system
        return 'map fields'
    },
    anotherMethod: function () {
        // I require another lib. Do I do that here or app.js?
        var kafka = require('kafka-node');
    }
};
```

Update: Regarding the close request for an opinion based answer is essentially telling me that this can be done either way, which is what I was trying to clarify.

Comment: You can require one module from multiple other modules.

Comment: utils should be requiring it's dependencies it depends on.

Comment: @Keith thanks, that is what I assumed. Is this done within the actual methods like my example or should it be declared above the `module.exports`?

Comment: It should be fine to include before you `module.exports`,.  But it's also possible to include inside your function,.  If you include in your function it will have the effect of late binding the module,.  So in some respects could improve load speed.